# writing a linked list queue class, but for some reason my head pointer reverts to garbage in my destructor when exiting the copy constructor

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor, copy-constructor

for some reason my program breaks after setting up debugging in the destructor after finishing its copy constructor test. I debugged through it and found out that for some reason the head pointer reverts to garbage as soon as it enters the destructor, even though the head pointer points correctly to the first node right as its exiting the copy constructor, and thus causes the assignment of the first link field in my destructor to fail.

when I ran the exam stub, it passed the heap test, and the copy constructor test right before breaking at destructor, why could this possibly be? btw i didnt include all of my code because I dont want a simple paste of fixed code, i just want to know why this is happening so I can learn.. I really didn't want to have to revert posting this question but i've been trying to figure out why this thing is acting this way and its driving me nuts..

here is my destructor with the point of break

```
PriorityQueue::~PriorityQueue( )
{
        Node *nodeptr, *nextnode=NULL;
        nodeptr = head_ptr;                     // CONTAINS GARBAGE AT POINT OF BREAK
        while ( nodeptr != NULL)
        {
                nextnode = nodeptr->link;  // THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS,
                delete nodeptr;             //BECAUSE ITS ASSIGNING GARBAGE FROM HEAD POINTER
                nodeptr = nextnode;
        }
        many_nodes = 0;
        head_ptr = NULL;
}
```

and here is my copy constructor

```
PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue(const PriorityQueue& source)
{   
    many_nodes = source.many_nodes;         // copy node count

    Node * node1 = NULL;                    // declare node pointer
    Node * precursor = NULL;                // declare precursor for new list 
    Node * copycursor = NULL;               // declare cursor for copy list

    copycursor = source.head_ptr;           // set copy cursor to source head

    int x = 0;
    while(x < many_nodes)               // start a loop for num of nodes
    {
        node1 = new Node;               // point node1 to a new allocated node

        node1->data = copycursor->data;         // copy over data to that node
        node1->priority = copycursor->priority;

        if (copycursor == source.head_ptr)      // if we're at the head
            head_ptr = node1;               // set new head to copy head

        if(precursor != NULL)               // if this isn't the first iteration
            precursor->link = node1;            // link the last node to this new node

        precursor = node1;              // precursor is now on this node
        copycursor = copycursor->link;          // copy cursor is now advanced

        x++;
    }
}
```

I also added a picture of my point where it breaks in the destructor to show the values easier
[image: my point of break]

[image: passes copy constructor and heap test..]

Comment: The constructor for `Node` is rather important here, as it should be defaulting its `link` to `nullptr`, and for that matter, should have a constructor that takes a data value *and* initializes `link` to `nullptr`; both in the initializer list of the ctor. And note: your list-copy is considerably more dense than it needs to be. A single pointer-to-pointer will clean that thing up substantially if you're interested.

Comment: Set a write breakpoint to see who is modifying it. Note that if `many_nodes` is zero (as it is in your screenshot), then `head_ptr` is uninitialized. Are you sure it's set correctly on exit from the copy constructor?

Comment: the specification doesn't require me to create a constructor for node though.. just to implement the methods already in the header..

Comment: whats a write breakpoint? im googling it..

Comment: Check your debugger documentation to see how to set a write breakpoint. But note also that `many_nodes` is zero, and you don't handle that case properly in your copy constructor. That's why I'm suspicious of your claim that everything is correct on exit from the copy constructor.

Comment: Your specification may not *require* initializing your members on construction, but this is C++, and touting around indeterminate pointers is *never* a grand idea. By not doing it in the constructors you're automatically taking on the responsibility of doing it manually *everywhere else*. I advise against that approach, sincerely.

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't recognize that fill-pattern at all, its not in any of the tables I regularly reference when seeing what appears to be pattern fills from the CRT, Win32, or .NET. Do you recognize it from anywhere? If not, I suspect as you it is quite-possibly an overwrite, but it would be a rather odd one.

Comment: @WhozCraig It may be a custom fill pattern provided by the instructor to catch exactly this bug.

Comment: interesting, I added
if(many_nodes == 0)
 {
  head_ptr = NULL;
  return;
 }
before the while loop in the copy constructor, and it caused it to get to the next test without breaking, then i had to do it for the assignment operator, but it fails the assignment operator test.. ill post its code up now

Comment: Please do not morph questions. One problem per question. Morphing the question invalidates previous answers and makes them nonsensical to future visitors. You may not realize it, but this Web site exists to be a resource for future visitors. That it also solves your problem is a side effect. Don't be selfish and treat it as your personal "help me" site.

Comment: Also, remember to cite this Web page when you submit your assignment. Claiming the work of others as your own is academically dishonest. Debugging is part of the essential work of programming.

Comment: I didn't morph the question, I left the original question the way it was, but left out the source code because I don't want everyone else who is taking the same class as me to copy the entire implementation. no where is the original "question" being morphed. All I did was remove the source code, and then under it, added an additional problem that arose. I left the question and the answer still makes sense, it tells people to never forget to check for the many_nodes = 0 case.

Comment: You changed the question by removing the original, important information and adding a new question. Don't do that. I've rolled your edit back.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in your copy constructor. If `many_nodes` is zero, then `head_ptr` is uninitialized. This is confirmed in in the screen shot: At the time of the crash, `many_nodes` is zero. (This means that your claim that "the head pointer points correctly to the first node right as its exiting the copy constructor" is incorrect. The head pointer did not revert to garbage. It was *already* garbage. That's probably what prevented people from diagnosing the real problem.)

**Update**: Well now you edited your question so it is now a completely unrelated question, so this answer and john's answer make no sense. This question is now useless to future visitors to the site, who will read the question and the answers and say "This is complete nonsense."

Comment: my claim was true that it was correctly pointing to the right head, when i stepped through in visual studio the watch window confirmed that it pointed to a linked list of 4 nodes, then once it entered the distructor, it reverted to 0 nodes and a garbage list. why do you have to act like you're attacking me? just because I deleted my code? I want to help everyone else in my class learn by not leaving the entire solution to the assignment up but i still left the question without the syntax up, it is still useful. sorry if I made you feel like i was misusing your help, you don't have to get

Comment: personal about it, and johns answer still makes sense without my code, but it isn't right anyway.

Comment: in case anyone cares... i sorta found a way around the stupid bug. i wrote 
if(many_nodes == 0)
 {
  head_ptr = NULL;
  return;
 }
at the begining of the destructor, seems like it would have been obvious since it breaks in the destructor, yet it passes the assignment operator test without the destructor!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
    node1->data = copycursor->data;         // copy over data to that node
    node1->priority = copycursor->priority;
```

to this

```
    node1->data = copycursor->data;         // copy over data to that node
    node1->priority = copycursor->priority;
    node1->link = NULL;
```

The problem you have is that the last node in your list is not getting it's link field set to NULL (I am assuming that the Node constructor doesn't do that).

Comment: @JL OK, well I think a complete program is going to be necessary to make any progress. Try and trim down the code as much as possible, but so that it is still showing this error, and then post all the code here.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out adding the test for 0 many_nodes in the destructor takes care of both the copy constructor and assignment operator from crashing, and the copy constructor and assignment operator still do their job as they meant to. this is confirmed with the screenshot here. credit to Ray for pointing out the 0 case. Now everyone reading this thread knows, how to write a well rounded destructor and copy constructor for a linked list class..

```
if(many_nodes == 0)
{
    head_ptr = NULL;
    return;
}
```

[image]